# Second order derivative of the squared Frobenius norm

Tags: matrices, derivatives, frobenius-method

I have a matrix $X$ of size $k\times d$. $k$ might be constrained to be equal to $d$.

I'm searching for the derivative of the following equation with respect to $X$:

$\Vert X^TX\Vert_F^2$

I tried to rewrite it using the trace:

$Tr(X^TX(X^TX)^H)$  but it doesn't seem to lead me anywhere.

I also tried to follow [a similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1902836/compute-the-derivate-of-square-frobenius-nom), but in my problem, the variable inside the norm is quadratic.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Introduce a new symmetric matrix variable
$$\eqalign{
 M &= X^TX \cr
dM &= dX^T\,X + X^T\,dX \cr
}$$
Then write the function using the trace/Frobenius product, i.e. $$A:B={\rm tr}(A^TB)$$
This makes finding the differential and gradient much easier.
$$\eqalign{
 \phi &= \|M\|_F^2 = M:M \cr
d\phi &= 2M:dM \cr
 &= 2M:(dX^T\,X + X^T\,dX) \cr
 &= 2MX^T:dX^T + 2XM:dX \cr
 &= 2XM^T:dX + 2XM:dX \cr
 &= 4XM:dX \cr
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial X} &= 4XM = 4XX^TX \cr
}$$